# jQuery $find method is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working on `aspx` page and I have following code:

```
function getActiveTab() {
    var tbcErrors = $find('<%=tbcErrors.ClientID%>');
    var index = tbcErrors.get_activeTabIndex();
    return tbcErrors.get_tabs()[index];
}
```

it worked fine but for unknown reason now i doesn't. And behaviour is very strange.

Now $find method returns null, ***but***, if I use `document.getElementById('ctl00_ctlMessageBox_ctlModalPopupAlert_updContainer')` or `$('#ctl00_ctlMessageBox_ctlModalPopupAlert_updContainer')` it works fine, and when I want to use $find (or see its declaration) i get following:

> $find function _Application$findComponent(id, parent) { /// Finds top-level components
>   that were added through addComponent if no parent is specified or
>   children of the specified parent. If parent is a

And i do not see any `$find(id)` method here. I downloaded latest jQuery 1.11.3 and get this error. It seems that `$find` method is just missing, but `$('#id')` works... Bizzare...

I can use `document.getElementById` but I want to understand this behaviour.

Comment: There's no `$find` in jQuery. This functions comes from elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `$find()` in jQuery. You need to use:

```
$('#<%=tbcErrors.ClientID%>');
```

The `$("#id")` is a jQuery way of getting `document.getElementById()`.

> `$get` & `$find` are shortcut functions Microsoft has built into their Ajax JavaScript Library.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, I was confused by `$find` and `$('').find`.

Comment: I don't understand some people. I am unable to delete my question but still receiving downvotes... It's not fair...

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy I will just vote you up. Don't worry.